# how to get permission result in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use a camera on my android. the user will be prompt for the permission of the camera. previously I used startActivityForResult and onRequestPermissionRequest for them. recently I found out that they are deprecated, so I'm trying out with registerForActivity. I managed to change to startActivity but I'm stuck at the permission request. I am wondering do I have to create another permissionlauncher or can I do the permission inside my resultlauncher.

```
    companion object{
        private const val CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 1
        private const val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2 
    }
val checkpermission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA

        var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val data: Intent? = result.data
                    val DP: Bitmap = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
                    val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageButtonVerifyPhoto)
                    image.setImageBitmap(DP)
                }

            }

        val permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){
                isGranted ->
            if(isGranted){
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) 
                resultLauncher.launch((intent))
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission is tested", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission is denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
        var cameraButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonRetakePhoto) // can change later

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    checkpermission
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ){
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) 
                resultLauncher.launch(intent)

            }else{
                permissionLauncher.launch(checkpermission)
            }
        }

    }
```

below is my previous code for the onRequestPermission

```
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(grantResults.isNotEmpty()&& grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) 
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission is denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Requesting runtime permissions is just a little more simplified

```
private val requestPermission =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
        // do something
    }
```

Now we can call this to get any type of permission you want

```
cameraButton.setOnClickListener {
        
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // Pass any permission you want while launching
            requestPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }
    }
```

Make sure to add in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0' // or later
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0' // or later
```

If you want to understand how all this works check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#kotlin)

Comment: may i check is the private necessary? i updated my code but there is a issue currently. i selected the 'ask every time' for the camera function but the second time i click on the camera function it did not prompt me for it same goes when i restart the app.

Answer (score 4):

Latest soluton in 2022: (no more request code)

1. Create Helper Extension Functions (for use in `Fragment`):

   ```
    fun Fragment.requestPermissions(request: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>, permissions: Array<String>) = request.launch(permissions)

    fun Fragment.isAllPermissionsGranted(permissions: Array<String>) = permissions.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
   ```
2. Request Permissions in `Fragment`:

   ```
    class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
        companion object {
            private val PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
        }

        private lateinit var binding: FragmentFirstBinding
        private lateinit var permissionsRequest: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
            permissionsRequest = getPermissionsRequest()

            binding.grantButton.setOnClickListener {
                requestPermissions(permissionsRequest, PERMISSIONS)     //extension function
            }

            return binding.root
        }

        private fun getPermissionsRequest() = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
            if (isAllPermissionsGranted(PERMISSIONS)) {             //extension function
                //do your stuff
            } else {
                //do your stuff
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Aaper](https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/aaper), it allows to request for permissions using annotations like so:

Fist, add the permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Then, annotate a method that needs to use the camera:

```
@EnsurePermissions(permissions = [Manifest.permission.CAMERA])  
fun takePhoto() {  
    Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  
}
```

That's it, when you call the `takePhoto` method, it'll check for the camera permission, and if it's not available it will launch a permission request dialog. If the user approves it, then it will proceed to run `takePhoto`s body.

Disclaimer, I'm the creator of Aaper